# Spark with Webhdfs/httpfs

Tags: apache-spark, webhdfs

I would like to read a file from HDFS into Spark via httpfs or Webhdfs.  Something along the lines of

> sc.textFile("webhdfs://myhost:14000/webhdfs/v1/path/to/file.txt")

or, ideally,

> sc.textFile("httpfs://myhost:14000/webhdfs/v1/path/to/file.txt")

Is there a way to get Spark to read the file over Webhdfs/httpfs?

Answer (score 0):

I believe WebHDFS/ HttpFS are like streaming sources to transmit the data over REST-API.

Then Spark Streaming can be used to receive the data from the WebHDFS/ HttpFS.

Comment: Hi Vijay, can you provide more detail on this?

Answer (score -1):

According to SPARK-2930 document enhancement request, spark.yarn.access.namenodes should also works for webhdfs / hdfs.
[SPARK-2930 clarify docs on using webhdfs with spark.yarn.access.namenodes](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2930)

[Running Spark on YARN](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)
Get more details about spark.yarn.access.namenodes