# how can a spark application access data on a remote hadoop cluster using webhdfs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, webhdfs

A spark application can access data on a remote hadoop environments using HDFS, however some hadoop clusters are limiting access to their data to WebHDFS so HDFS access is not available.

How can my spark application access data on a remote hadoop environment using webhdfs?

I have seen this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367962/spark-with-webhdfs-httpfs).  The other question is different to this one because it does not state that the spark environment and hadoop environments are separate environments.